# How to separate strings from csv file using php?

Tags: php, csv, delimiter

How can I separate the strings from csv file by using `","` or `"\r\n"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate string

```
<?php
    $csv_string = file_get_contents("file.csv");
    $separated = explode("\n", $csv_string);
    print_r($separated);
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any newline on your csv string. Is that was removed?

Answer (score 1):

use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$string=Dateiname;Stueckzahl;Termin;Auftragsnummer;Position;Bemerkung;Maschine;Material;Dicke;Gewicht;Bemerkung_1;Bemerkung_2;Kanten 58117600-3;10;20170807;107;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;0,05311;LASER;;FABRICATION BAY 58171100-04;2;20170807;106;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;0,34630;LASER;;FABRICATION BAY 58383310;3;20170807;111;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;0,11151;LASER;BENDING; 1404704000-1;7;20170807;108;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;5,45,241;LASER;;FABRICATION BAY 1404704000-3;14;20170807;110;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;0,24598;LASER;BENDING;FABRICATION BAY 58171100-03;6;20170807;105;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;0,39093;LASER;BENDING;FABRICATION BAY 58656800;2;20170807;113;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;0,18605;LASER;BENDING;FABRICATION BAY 58383420;3;20170807;112;;For May week 1;L3050 5,0KW;CRCA;1,50,000;0,23491;LASER;BENDING;

   $string= str_replace(";",",",$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the php csv functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```